# How does Melf's Minute Meteors interact with another spell with a casting time of 1 action on subsequent rounds of combat?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spellcasting, action-economy

The [*Melf's Minute Meteors*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/melfs-minute-meteors) spell states (XGE, page 161, emphasis mine):

> [...] When you cast the spell—and **as a bonus action on each of your turns thereafter**—you can expend one or two of the meteors, sending them streaking toward a point or points you choose within 120 feet of you. [...]

My question is: **If I cast *Melf's Minute Meteors* on the first turn of combat, how does it interact with another spell with a casting time of 1 action on the subsequent rounds of combat?**

Could I for example, on the second round of combat, cast a [*Scorching Ray*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/scorching-ray) (PHB, page 273; SRD) followed by two of the meteors for a total of five fire blows? Three attack rolls and two Dexterity saving throws. Is that all correct?

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate, as it has been asked before. Let us know if that question doesn't clear things up for you.

Comment: Generally speaking, we prefer to leave duplicate questions undeleted—the duplicate question box with links to the original question can help others find it.

Comment: @KRyan thank you. I have fixed it.